# how to get data in single array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, grouping

**I want to achieve my documents in a single array**
**My data is this:**

```
    "summary_data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60418b730ba57044ec0afddd"),
            "category" : "Entertainment",
            "name" : "Alia bhatt",
            "profession" : "acting"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60418bc838497d42a80879e3"),
            "category" : "Entertainment",
            "name" : "priyanka chopra",
            "profession" : "acting"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60418bef38497d42a80879eb"),
            "category" : "Entertainment",
            "name" : "radhika apte",
            "profession" : "acting"
        }, 
        
        
    ]
}
```

**And i want data like this having min 10(limit) category data of each category.How can achieve this:**

```
"summary_data" : [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60418b730ba57044ec0afddd"),
    "data": [{
      "Entertainment": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("60418ce138497d42a8087a03"),
        "category": "Entertainment",
        "name": "Alia bhatt",
        "profession": "acting"
    }],
      
 }]
```

**i have tried many queries some of them are:**

```
db.getCollection('experts').aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { category: "Sports" },
            { category: "other" },
            { category: "Entertainment" }
          ]
        }
      },
      { $limit: 10 },
      {
        $group:
        {
          _id: null,
          summary_data: {
            $push: {
              _id: "$_id",
              category: "$category",
              name: "$name",
              profession: "$profession",
            }
          },
        }
      },
    ])
```

Please help me to build this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain your expected result, 1) what is the `_id` along with `data` 2) where is the other 2 documents in `data`?